# Facebook share button screen- Resize possible?

Tags: facebook

I will really appreciate if some one can help me with resizing the share screen window (After I click share, the window that gets open)

Is that possible to do that? If yes, how?
I don't have any tech exp, so please don't save on details :)

Comment: What does your code look like now? What have you tried to do to resize the window?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can pass dimensions to the facebook api call

That is the syntax for the comments box you might be able to use the same for you share window.

hope that helps